# How to find a difference between two dates from WPF Extended Toolkit?

Tags: c#, wpf, datetime, datetimepicker, wpf-extended-toolkit

I am using DateTimePicker from WPF Extended Tooklit(http://wpftoolkit.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=DateTimePicker&referringTitle=Documentation)

So, I have two values: Start Time and End Time (both are DateTimePickers from WPF Extended Toolkit), how can I find difference between these values? Also, I want to find difference between Start Time and DateTime.Now to print how much time left.

Thanks in advance.

---

```
DateTime? firstDate = datetimepicker1.Value;
DateTime? secondDate = datetimepicker2.Value;
TimeSpan? duration = firstDate - secondDate;
string d = duration.ToString();
```

That worked for me.
Thank you, ry8806 and Chris Schubert!

Comment: What do you mean with difference? You want to do `EndTime` - `StartTime`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the `DateTime`'s subtract method.  It will return a `TimeSpan` which has the duration properties you're looking for.

```
DateTime? firstDate = picker.SelectedDate;
DateTime? secondDate = picker2.SelectedDate;

    if (firstDate!= null && secondDate != null)
    {
        TimeSpan duration = firstDate.Subtract(secondDate);
        return duration.TotalDays;
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do

```
TimeSpan duration = endTime - startTime;
```

Then on the [Timespan](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.timespan(v=vs.110).aspx) (duration) you can access many properties e.g.:

```
duration.TotalSeconds
duration.TotalMinutes
```